# Why in C# an explicit decimal => long conversion operator is called implicitly, losing precision?

Tags: c#, decimal, long-integer, implicit

The following C# program *silently and implicitly* calls an *explicit* decimal-to-long conversion operator, losing precision.

I don't understand why this happens. As far as I understand, in C# explicit operator should not be called implicitly by the language. Especially that in this case the silent explicit conversion is losing precision (1.1M => 1L).

This odd behavior actually caused a bug in my program.

Here is the simplified code:

```
// Custom number class
struct Num
{
    long Raw;
    public static implicit operator Num(long v) => new Num { Raw = v };
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        decimal d = 1.1m;
        // The following line implicitly converts d to long (silently losing precision), 
        // then calls Num.op_Implicit(long)
        Num num = (Num)d;  // <=== should not compile???
    }
}
```

Here is the resulting IL. You can see that `System.Decimal::op_Explicit` is called, even though it's never asked for.

```
IL_0000: ldc.i4.s 11
IL_0002: ldc.i4.0
IL_0003: ldc.i4.0
IL_0004: ldc.i4.0
IL_0005: ldc.i4.1
IL_0006: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.Decimal::.ctor(int32, int32, int32, bool, uint8)
IL_000b: stloc.0
IL_000c: ldloc.0
IL_000d: call int64 [mscorlib]System.Decimal::op_Explicit(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal)  // <=== ???
IL_0012: call valuetype Num Num::op_Implicit(int64)
IL_0017: stloc.1
IL_0018: ret
```

Comment: `Num num = d;`, now it is implicit.

Comment: @HansPassant Conversion to Num is not the issue. Conversion to long is.

Comment: An explicit conversion requires a (cast).  The snippet definitely shows a cast.  Not sure how that happened, possibly because the implicit conversion produced an error message.  Once bitten, twice shy, get ahead by removing the conversion operator and adding a FromLong(long) method.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The rules for user defined explicit conversions are given in the C# spec. [10.5.5 User-defined explicit conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#1055-user-defined-explicit-conversions). The rules are quite complex, but specifically allow for additional explicit conversions to be performed “implicitly”:

> …
> If `E` does not already have the type `Sₓ`, then a standard explicit conversion from `E` to `Sₓ` is performed.
> …

(Here `E` is the source type - `decimal` and `Sₓ` is the type your conversion operator converts from - `long`).

Note that you are performing an explicit conversion to `Num` (even though it uses the implicit operator you have defined), so the rules for explicit conversions are followed, which allows the extra “implicit” explicit conversion from `decimal` to `long`.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say that `Num num = (Num)d;` is very, very explicit because `(Num)` is put right in front of `d`.

It looks like the compiler sees you want an explicit cast, and then it does `(Num)(long)d` because `d` is a `decimal` and (Num) enables it to "force" a long out of the decimal. I have to be honest that I'm guessing, but it could be an explanation.

The following would be implicit, in my (not so expert) opinion:

```
Num num = d;
```

And indeed that does not compile with the given struct.

Comment: Yes, what else can be more explicit than a *direct explict cast* `(Num)`

Comment: You misunderstood the question. The implicit conversion to long is called, not to Num.

Comment: I updated my answer to give a *possible* explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The rules for explicit conversion are incredibly complex in C# (wart).

The [C# draft specification section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#1055-user-defined-explicit-conversions) that explains how a user-defined explicit conversion is called has a lot of sub-cases for different type possiblities. Note that the specification hasn't been updated, and seems to have some errors / be inconsistent.

In your example, I think these are the rules that apply:

- A user-defined explicit conversion from an expression `d` to a type `Num` is processed as follows:
- If `d` has a type, let `S` be that type.

  - let `Sᵢ` and `Tᵢ` be `Decimal` and `Num`
  - let `S₀` and `T₀` be `Decimal` and `Num`
- Find the set of types, `D`, from which user-defined conversion operators will be considered. This set consists of `Decimal` and `Num`.
- If a standard implicit conversion exists from a type `long` to type `Decimal`, then `long` is said to be encompassed by `Decimal`.
- Find the set of applicable user-defined conversion operators, `U`. This set consists of the user-defined explicit conversion operators declared by the structs in { `Decimal`, `Num` } that convert from a type encompassed by `Decimal` to `Num`.

> `U` is `public static implicit operator Num(long v)`

- Find the most-specific source type, `Sₓ`, of the operators in `U`:

  - `Sₓ` is the most-encompassing type in the combined set of source types of the operators in `U`

  > `Sₓ` is `long`
- If `d` does not already have the type `long`, then a standard explicit conversion from `d` to `long` is performed.

Answer (score -1):

The [C# reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/numeric-conversions#explicit-numeric-conversions) documents built-in numeric conversions. Conversion from decimal to long is one of these conversions and that this will be performed using an explicit numeric conversion. It is valid C# syntax, and will compile. The reference highlights the fact that data loss is possible. It also states that the conversion uses rounding.

While this behaviour is not what you desire: it is specified in the official documentation. While data loss is possible, the alternative would be to disallow it, which would be harsh restriction. The language designers had to make a call, and chose the possibility of data loss instead of disallowing it.

Comment: Asker's question is about how the narrowing conversion (from `decimal` to `long`) is being done without being specifically asked for, when it says at the top of that very page you link: "You must use a cast expression to perform an explicit conversion." Asker's code does not have a cast expression **from `decimal` to `long`** so how is it being done? (Iridium [has provided the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76336627))